# Create cards dynamically from the DB and show in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, asp.net, html

I'm working on a personal project using the framework: [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/).

I've run into a problem when creating the cards components from the database. Now all I have from the code is XHTML 5.

[image]

I researched about creating dynamic components in HTML 5, but not achieving the desired result.

The cards have three objects `image`, two links for gift card and catalog.

How can I dynamically generate these cards?

Comment: Welcome to SO. what have you done so far and where did you stucked.

Comment: So it appears you are using mySQL, but some code in terms of what you have tried would be helpful so we can see what your problems are.

Comment: Thanks, this is a piece of code to create a card.

<div class="col s4">
<div class="card">
<div class"card-image">
<img src="Logo.png"/>
</div>
<div class="card-action">
<a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal_tr01">Gift Card</a>
<a class="modal-trigger" href="#emp02">Catalog</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

In my database I have a table that stores the following: id, company name, image path, image path catalog, id country.

Most of these cards is created using the tag <div> so I researched how to dynamically create these tags, but idk how to create the set of cards ,if using js or do it with c #.

Comment: Sorry if i dont markdown my code.